# Could users have a dedicated Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange email address?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

On multiple occasions, people have tried to connect with me using Facebook because of Stack Overflow. My Facebook account is private, and I would rather not have my email address on show in my Stack Overflow profile.

Would it be possible for users to have/earn an so email account after either on joining or after reaching a certain level of rep (e.g. 1000)?

What do other users think?

Comment: For what purpose? SO is not a social site so there would be no point in SO offering a email account, if it's for having something for people to send emails to, then there's PLENTY of free providers already, just create an' email account solely for SO then.

Comment: At the moment, an official @stackoverflow.com address is an indicator that the sender is officially affiliated with the company, as either an employee or a moderator. Changing that would open the door to abuse. Plus there's a whole host of technical issues and ongoing maintenance work that this would entail. To properly maintain the infrastructure for this would likely cost tens or even hundreds of thousands every year

Comment: How is this any different from the various feature requests to add user-to-user private communication (PM system), which are always declined?

Comment: What I have done when creating sockp-.... *cough* needing to hide my E-Mail is create a new address with a free provider who does forwarding. That's probably the ideal way to protect your E-Mail address currently.

Comment: Turns out we are all @Pekka웃 's socks ...

Comment: *On multiple occasions, people have tried to connect with me using Facebook because of stackoverflow.* - I'm surprised this question isn't about how to discourage this behavior altogether. (There probably isn't much we can do but it's still creepy.)

Answer (score 10):

> Would it be possible for users to have/earn an so email account after either on joining or after reaching a certain level of rep (e.g. 1000) ?

Sorry, but no.

These email addresses are for staff only.

---

> I would rather not have my email address on show in my so profile

We don't show it (that is, any email address supplied specifically on an email address field in your settings) - if you choose to display it on your "about me", that's completely up to you (it is also up to you what email address you put there - doesn't have to be your main one or one that identifies you).

Comment: Well in DCU, my college, for example, staff emails go to Dcu.ie while student emails are to mail.dcu.ie.  Surely there must be some way of doing something similar to this ?

Comment: @RachelGallen - we are not an email service provider, nor do we wish to become one. The administrative overhead for this is high and not something we are willing to consider at this time.

Comment: I only asked if it was possible. There's no need to be so ratty about it.

Comment: Sorry if I came across that way. Not trying to be "ratty" about it, but to explain **why** we won't do it. We try to be open about things here.

Comment: @RachelGallen: Oded provided a perfectly valid explanation as to why this request isn't being considered. I think you may be underestimating the effort, time, and cash it takes to provide an email service on this scale.